# Trying to Install Orange-3 Text Mining Add In [Error] - Command failed: python python -m pip install Orange3-Text exited with non zero status

Tags: macos, text-mining, orange

I am trying to install the Text add-in for Orange 3 but I get this error each time:

> Command failed: python python -m pip install Orange3-Text exited with non zero status.

My pip is up to date too so I'm not sure what the issue is or how I can get around this. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Tried installing through pip command line tools and ended up with this error:

Comment: Command "/Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/q_/rdqs2bwn52v05y77gv2bcdfw0000gn/T/pip-build-fiqxlkcl/ufal.udpipe/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/q_/rdqs2bwn52v05y77gv2bcdfw0000gn/T/pip-eus4746f-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q_/rdqs2bwn52v05y77gv2bcdfw0000gn/T/pip-build-fiqxlkcl/ufal.udpipe/

Comment: I installed the Text add-on via Terminal by following the instructions from the github page https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text 

When I run Orange from Terminal with 
`python -m Orange.canvas`  
the Text Mining tab is available. However when I open it by double-clicking at the icon from e.g. dock it's not ... can someone tell me whats the difference?

Comment: @meier_flo When you install Orange from the package, it creates a separate virtual environment where it install all the dependencies and add-ons. You have likely installed Text in some other virtual environment. These seem like two Oranges that you have.

Answer (score 1):

This should be solved with the latest build of Text. I am sorry for this mess, it is my fault. We had to put ufal.udpipe dependency on conda and it took a while. Now it should be fixed.